# Manipulating an elements background

Tags: html, image, css

When you have an image inside a div, say:

```
<div class="reflection">
<img src="example" alt="" />
</div>
```

You can reference the specific element only using `.reflection img { // do stuff here }`

I want to reference only a `background:` of a CSS element as I am using templates and all images are displayed using CSS and not HTML like so:

```
.exampleClass { background: url("path here") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; }
```

How can I reference that background of that class in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Just create it's own class..

**HTML**

```
<div class="reflection background">
<img src="example" alt="" />
```

**CSS**

```
.background { background: url("path here") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; }
```

That `.background` class can be given to any element you want to have the background.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.reflection {}` and manipulate the background. It's a CSS property (`background`) so you can change it later on after it was originally defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 2 classes. Ie:

```
<div class="reflection defaultBackground">
    <img src="example" alt="" />
</div>
```

You can then put styling on both .reflection img aswell as .defaultBackground img.